# Filtering all rows based on one value

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that hold data for my call center's application.

Table A has one row of data per call which holds basic information like customer name, call reference and log and close times.

Table B can hold multiple rows per call based on the number of times the call gets updated. Both tables hold a unique call reference for the call.

I been asked to filter calls that have been passed from our 1st Line to our Sales team.
The only way I can determine if a call has done this is by looking at table b. Where the update text will contain "Call assigned to the 'Office01/SALES/'

I tried to filter this in my where clause, however obviously it only filters the row and not all rows for the call. Is there any way I can filter all rows from table b if the my update field contains the above?

I am running MYSQL 5.0

Many thanks

Comment: please post what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `exists` clause:

```
select * 
from tableB b 
where exists (
  select 1 
  from tableB b1
  where
    b.uniquekey = b1.uniquekey
    and b.updatetext = 'Office01/SALES/'
)
```